# Signing Up in Firebase Authentication returns null for displayName in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I have recently started learning `Firebase Authentication` and now I want to implement it in a React app.

The app used to work fine with Firebase Auth `signup and signin` when `signup and signin` was in Auth component. But now I separated `signup and signin` in their own components and the app breaks.

The problem takes place after a user signs up. That is `displayName` is null. But if I refresh the page at that moment, then it's not null anymore.

Here's the result when I signup:

[image]
[image]
Here's the code:

Auth Component:

```
const Auth = ( props ) => {
    
    const [ user, setUser ]                         = useState(null);
    const [ displayName, setDisplayName ]           = useState(null);
    
    useEffect(() => {

        const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((authUser) => {
            if (authUser) {
                
                console.log('user object FROM AUTH.js ', authUser);
                console.log('displayName FROM AUTH.js ', authUser.displayName);

                setDisplayName(authUser.displayName);
                setUser(authUser);

            } else {
                
                setDisplayName(null);
                setUser(null);

            }
        });

        return () => {
            
            unsubscribe();

        };
    }, [user]);


    const signOut = () => {
        setUser(null);
        auth.signOut();
    };

    const modalShow = (action, type) => {
        if ( type === "Signin" ) {
            return setModalShowSignIn(action);
        }else if ( type === "Signup") {
            return setModalShowSignUp(action);
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            
            <Signup modal={modalShow} modalState={modalShowSignUp} />
            <Signin modal={modalShow} modalState={modalShowSignIn} />

        </div>
    );
};
```

Signup.js

```
const Signup = ( props ) => {

    const [ fullName, setFullName ]                 = useState('');
    const [ password, setPassword ]                 = useState('');
    const [ email, setEmail ]                       = useState('');
    const [ url, setURL ]                           = useState('');

    const signUp = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        auth
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then((authUser) => {
                props.modal(false);
                return authUser.user.updateProfile({
                    displayName: fullName,
                    photoURL: url,
                });
            })
            .catch((error) => alert(error.message));
    };

    const modalClose = () => {
        props.modal(false, "Signup");
    };

    return (
        <>
            <div>

                <form onSubmit={signUp} >

                    <input
                        type='text'
                        value={fullName}
                        onChange={(e) => setFullName(e.target.value)}
                    />
                        
                    <input
                        type='url'
                        value={url}
                        onChange={(e) => setURL(e.target.value)}
                    />
                        
                    <input
                        type='email'
                        value={email}
                        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                    />

                    <input
                        type='password'
                        value={password}
                        onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                    />

                    <button type='submit'>Sign Up</button>
                </form>
            </div>

        </>
    );
};
```

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the response before the promise fullfilled. You should use any async await method, or put the useState method in the then method.

```
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged().then((res) => {

                if (res) {
                
                console.log('user object FROM AUTH.js ', res);
                console.log('displayName FROM AUTH.js ', res.displayName);

                setDisplayName(res.displayName);
                setUser(res);

            } else {
                
                setDisplayName(null);
                setUser(null);

            }

})
```

Comment: Hey man. I just tried with async await method. The issue is still there. Then I tried using then method as you have shown in your code. The app breaks with some weird errors. I can't even sign up now.

Comment: Any suggestion?

Comment: I think i about and will write.